# school diary, Student model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a Student model and want to create a school diary. I want to be able to add subject and then mark (2-5). Should I create 3 models (Student, Subject, Mark) ? Im thinking of making Mark model as enum, is this a good approach ? Marks should be fixed (2-5).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is clear or not. But why don't you have one Student model, and use Subject and Mark as attributes?

Comment: Obviously you can have Subject and Mark as Models if they have lots of attributes and things to do. Then just make some association between the 3 models.